# VBA - Access emailing

Tags: vba

I have a table of 1000 emails with unique identifiers and 5 other tables with matching unique identifiers. I am trying to email attachments from the first table the attachments from the remaining 5 table. one issue is that all information is store on the 5 tables. is there code I can write to "automate" the emailing without having to write thousands lines of code?

Comment: are the tables in a database? If so, you can probably write a single sql query to get what you need. Maybe you can provide some sample data?

Comment: yes, that are all in a single Database. how would i Link data?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide sample data. I assume by 'emails' you mean email addresses.

Let's say the table with mail addresses is called 'accounts'. It is not clear why there are 5 other tables. Let's assume they are called a, b, c, d and e. The information in these tables is stored in field 'info'. You did not provide information on the type of database (access, mysql, postgres, oracle, ms-sql), so I am going to use as generic SQL as possible. Let's assume the id field in accounts is called 'id' and the corresponding field in the other tables is called 'accountid'. (**Edit:**)Let's assume the other tables do not all reference all 1000 accounts.

```
select accounts.email, a.info, b.info, c.info, d.info, e.info
 from accounts left join a on accounts.id=a.accountid 
   left join b on accounts.id=b.accountid
    left join c on and accounts.id=c.accountid 
     left join d on account.id=d.accountid 
      left join e on account.id=e.accountid;
```

Note that for some accounts some of the info fields may be empty (NULL) if the corresponding table does not have a row referencing the account.